# Did Starfleet Ever Re-Encounter John Doe?

Tags: star-trek

In the ST TNG episode, Transfigurations (S3 E25), “John Doe” is discovered inside an escape pod and over the course of the episode, is transfigured into his species’ next evolutionary state, which obviously comes with quite a few perks.

Did Starfleet ever encounter “energy being John Doe” again? Or was his exit from the Enterprise D the only time they would ever encounter him?

Asking in context to Canon timeline. Novelizations/web info are acceptable.

Comment: What about John doe

Answer (score 5):

No, at least not as far as we know.  Neither Memory Alpha nor Memory Beta have any mention or reference to John Doe or his species the Zalkonian outside of the episode Transfigurations.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/John_Doe
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Transfigurations_(episode)
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zalkonian
https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Transfigurations

Comment: Seems like his species was well on their way to rivaling they Q.....

Comment: Perhaps, but I think they'd still have a long old way to go. Seems though that we'll never know.

Comment: They'd have a really, really far way to go. I'm not sure how you make such an extrapolation.

Comment: What a coincidence, John Doe-lancie plays Q!